# Size of elements in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I am new to QML.
As I understand, all elements have an associated width and height which determines their size.
If the user changes screen resolution, the final output looks weird.
Is there a way the size of elements could be controlled dynamically based on screen resolution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using fixed values, you can multiply `height` and `width` of the root element by factors, that determine the size of your elements proportional to the root elements size. Additionally you can use [QML anchors](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qml-anchor-layout.html). With this you can create completely scalable GUIs:

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Item {
    id: root

    // default size, but scalable by user
    height: 300; width: 400

    Rectangle {
        id: leftPanel

        anchors {
            top: parent.top
            left: parent.left
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }
        width: root.width * 0.3
        color: "blue"
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: topPanel

        anchors {
            top: parent.top
            left: leftPanel.right
            right: parent.right
        }
        height: root.height * 0.2
        color: "green"
    }


    Rectangle {
        id: contentArea

        anchors {
            top: topPanel.bottom
            left: leftPanel.right
            right: parent.right
            bottom: root.bottom
        }
        color: "white"

        Text {
            text: "Hi, I'm scalable!"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            font.pixelSize: root.width * 0.05
        }
    }
}
```

I dont know a way to get the screen resolution with pure QML that is available at all environments.

To determine the screen resolution on mobile devices you can use the [QML Screen Element](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qt-components-symbian-1.0/qml-screen.html).

In desktop applications you can get the screen resolution in C++ (e.g. with [QDesktopWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdesktopwidget.html)) and make it [available in QML](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtbinding.html).

Comment: The [QML Screen Element](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-screen.html) is also available in QML 5.